# How to mark checkboxes in a list backward, numerically descending?

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

I am generating a list from a database using PHP. Each line is numbered in ascending order and contains a checkbox. If you select one, all checkboxes above it, numerically descending, should also be selected.

I have already tried various things, but it does not work.
Here is the code in a shortened form:

```
<table id="mySEARCH" class="shoppinglist-content">
<!-- ******************************************************************************** shopping list beginn-->
    <!-- script test start -->
    <?php
        if(isset($_COOKIE['shoppinglist'])){
            $list = $_COOKIE['shoppinglist'];
            $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `$list`");
            $stmt->execute();
            $x = 0;
            foreach($stmt as $item)
            { $x++;?>
                <tr id="line<?php echo $x;?>" style="opacity: 1.0;">
                <td class="split-list"><input type="checkbox" id="split-list-<?php echo $x;?>" name="split-list" onchange="markAbove<?php echo $x;?>()" value="<?php echo $x;?>"></td>
                </tr>
                <script>
                    function markAbove<?php echo $x;?>(){
                        var choosedLine = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]");
                        for(var i = <?php echo $x;?>; i > choosedLine.value; i--){
                            choosedLine.setAttribute("checked", "");
                        }
                        console.log(i);
                    }
                </script>
            <?php
            }
        }else {
/******************************************************************************** shopping list end****/
            ?><tr><td></td><td></td><td>Keine Items vorhanden</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr><?php
        }
    ?>
<!-- script test end -->
</table>
```

[image]

Does anyone have a tip on how this can work?

Comment: Can you show the *rendered* php?

Comment: There is a screenshot behind the link

Comment: I meant the plain html, after the php has been compiled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not add your function inside the loop.
You can do something like below. In javascript we can listen to checkbox change and grab the parent tr from that element. We then loop to find previous tr's and find checkbox inside it.

Haven't tested the code but you will get idea

```js
const allCheckboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');
allCheckboxes.forEach(function(checkbox) {
  checkbox.addEventListener('change', function() {
    let elem = this.closest('tr');
    while (elem = elem.previousElementSibling) {
      elem.querySelector('input[type="checkbox"]').checked = true;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I've tested the code in a extra file but it doesn't work. In my productive code aint as well.

Comment: Yes, I was able to replicate your code. Thx a lot!
But, if I embend this to my productive code, I got:
Uncaught TypeError: elem.querySelector(...) is null.
In console I get all correct input nodes

Comment: All your table rows have this input checkbox right? So this should not happen. However you can add an extra check in while condition like: let isCheckbox = elem.querySelector('input[type="checkbox"]');
      if (isCheckbox) {
       isCheckbox.checked = true;
      }

Comment: Jaaaaaaaaa, now it works! Thx a lot! :)